# How do I avoid a PMD CloseResource violation?

Tags: pmd

I'm modifying my application code in order to respect the pmd rules. I had a Close Resource error in this code:

```
Connection c = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
Statement request = null;
try {
    request = c.createStatement();
    request.execute(loadDataRequest);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    dataLogger.error(e);
    throw e;
}
```

So I searched and found an apache utility for avoiding it: DButils
My code became like this

```
Connection c = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
Statement request = null;
try {
    request = c.createStatement();
    request.execute(loadDataRequest);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    dataLogger.error(e);
    throw e;
} finally {
    DbUtils.closeQuietly(request);
    DbUtils.closeQuietly(c);            
}
```

However, I'm still having the PMD alert in eclipse and sonar reports! Do you have any idea how to fix that permanently?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `closeTargets` property of the CloseResource PMD rule. When PMD finds similar method names as in the `closeTargets` property, it won't fire the warning message:

```
<properties>
    <property name="types" value="Connection,Statement,ResultSet"/>
    <property name="closeTargets" value="closeQuietly, closeConnection, close"/>
</properties>
```

Alternatively, you can use [SourceMeter](https://www.sourcemeter.com/), which includes this configuration natively.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that PMD doesn't know closeQuietly() closes the connection.  And it isn't that smart because if your method was named close() you'd have the same problem.  And since it is a Java rule, it isn't easy to change the implementation because then you'd have to repackage the Eclipse and Sonar PMD plugins to recognize your copy of the rule.

Your options:
1) Add //NOPMD comment to suppress
2) Refactor the code to get/close the connection in a superclass so you only have it once.

Answer (score 1):

PMD defines a parameter for this rule called `closeTargets`. By default, this parameter is set to `close` method. You can change it for specifying `DbUtils.closeQuietly`